# how to load image on webview from ms-appdata:///local

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm developing windows store apps with html5/javascript.
    I have to load image from src " ms-appdata://local/testimage.png" to webview.I can't able to load the image using this src on navigateToString method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `ms-appx-web` scheme.

I believe that if you place the content in a subfolder, `ms-appdata` should work too.

More on this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)

Comment: i can't use ms-appx-web because my downloaded images in msappdata://local/imageset/..ms-appdata not working on webview when images in subfolder.pls help me

Answer (score 4):

I recently updated my  Visual Studio 2015  apache cordova project to visual studio 2017. I had few problems with working with angular js otherwise everything worked in windows 10 environment.

But what I noticed was images from ms-appdata:///local folder couldn't load  to img tags. I tried many ways like row html, dynamic tag creation and add url as a base64 data url.

In base64 solution it worked. But I want to get the file itself  as my app was supporting iOS and Android as well.

So after trying hundred things solutions was simple.  You have to set img-src  option to All ( *  ) Content-Security-Policy meta tag of the html file.

Please check following screen shot. You need to add the part with the read border to load image resources from any location.

[image]